# UML Class-Diagram, association: class -> interface

Tags: java, interface, uml

How can I visualize that a class only holds a reference to a interface of a specific class? Can i use associations between classes and interfaces ?

For example:

```
class A implements aInterface{
...
}

class B {
aInterface interfaceOfA;
...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, exactly like that.

Use the association `aInterface interfaceOfA` or use association `A a` because `A` implements `aInterface` and the class `A` has the methods written out

To visualize, draw an interface aInterface, and 2 classes, `A` and `B`.
A implements `aInterface`, so there has to be an "implementline" from aInterface to `A`. `B` has association `interfaceOfA`, so there has to be an "associationline" from `B` to `aInterface`.

Clear?

Comment: Is the line from class A to the interface from type "Realize" ? Is there a way to clarify that I mean the class A which implements this interface ? For example if there where a addition class C which implements the interface too.

Comment: Yes, if a class implements an interface, we visualize it by using a realization-line. And for the code itself, just use the class A, which implements the interface. Easy.

Answer (score 1):

UML Diagram can look like this:

[image]